# node.js retrieve form input values sent by client

Tags: jquery, node.js

i can't figure out why i can't retrieve the form input values in node.js sent by a jquery ajax call:

here is the client side jQuery code:

```
$('#send-button').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var str = $('#form-contact').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "contact",
  data: str,
  success: function(msg) {
    ....
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
    ....
  }
})
```

now in node.js i try to retrieve the data send by the jQuery ajax request:

```
var sys = require("sys"),  
    http = require("http"),  
    url = require("url"),  
    path = require("path"),  
    qs = require('querystring'),
    fs = require("fs"),

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) { 

    .....

    path.exists(filename, function(exists) {  
        if(!exists) { 
            if (paramUri == "/contact") {

              if (request.method == 'POST') {
                var body = '';

                request.on('data', function(chunk) {
                  body += chunk;
                });

                request.on('end', function() {
                  console.log(body);
                })

              }

              response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
              response.end('worked');
              return;
            }

            response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");  
            response.end();  
            return;  
        }  

      ......
    });  
})

server.listen(8080);
```

but the request.on('data') and request.on('end') are never called. i am using node.js -v 0.2.6

Comment: I can't think of anything that would break this from looking at the code, does the response work correctly? Have you checked whether the listeners are actually added? Would be great if you could either provide us more information or post the full code so we can test things out. PS: You have a very inconsistent coding style.

Comment: btw, the identifier `XMLHttpRequest` is already taken (in the browsers). Don't use it as an parameter name. Use `xhr` instead (for instance)

Comment: @Ivo i don't care for the coding style right now, i am just experimenting with node.js and try to solve my problem. BTW this code is mostly from a tutorial. @response yes it works, client receives the string "worked"

Answer (score 1):

You are using `path.exists()` which is a async function. This becomes a problem when you register your request listeners not until you're acutally executing  this callback.

The solution is to pause the request before you execute `path.exists()` and resume it in the callback:

```
...
request.pause();
path.exists(filename, function(exists) {  
    //register request listeners
    ...
    request.resume();
}
```